# How to write query for selection using null

Tags: sql

This is my table:

```
id  name   level    m_id    password
3   rr      1        5        rr
4   ss      1       null      ss
5   aa      1        8        aa
6   ee      1        2        ee
7   vv      1       null      vv
```

I want to select records which contain `m_id=null`

I tried writing the query like this, but it not returning any records at all instead of the two records which contain `null` as expected.

```
select * from project where m_id=null;
```

Comment: Use `is null` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `is` operator

```
select * from project where m_id is null
```

Because comparing with `null` leads to *unknown* if you don't use a null-safe operator.

Comment: Should also note when negating this, it is `m_id is not null`.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `is`instead `=` to select `null` entries.

In your case,

```
select * from project where m_id is null;
```